# openGL ES - change the render mode from RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY to RENDERMODE_CONTINUOUSLY on touch

Tags: android, opengl-es, game-mechanics, movement, touch

i want to change the rendermode from RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY to RENDERMODE_CONTINUOUSLY when i touch the screen.

WHAT i Need :
Initially the object should be stationary. after touching the screen, it should move automatically. The motion of my object is a projectile motion ans it is working fine.

what i get : Force close and a NULL pointer exception.

My code :

public class BallThrowGLSurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView{

```
MyRender _renderObj;
Context context;
GLSurfaceView glView;

public BallThrowGLSurfaceView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    _renderObj = new MyRender(context);
    this.setRenderer(_renderObj);
    this.setRenderMode(RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY);
    this.requestFocus();
    this.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    glView = new GLSurfaceView(context.getApplicationContext());
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (event != null)
    {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        {
            if (_renderObj != null)
            {   Log.i("renderObj", _renderObj + "lll");
                // Ensure we call switchMode() on the OpenGL thread.
                // queueEvent() is a method of GLSurfaceView that will do this for us.
                queueEvent(new Runnable()
                {
                    public void run()
                    {
                        glView.setRenderMode(RENDERMODE_CONTINUOUSLY);      
                    }
                });
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);   
}
```

}

PS : i know that i am making some silly mistakes in this, but cannot figure out what it really is.

Comment: Could you add the NullPointerException.printStackTrace() to the question please?

Comment: @DanielCarlsson it is giving at this line.

glView.setRenderMode(RENDERMODE_CONTINUOUSLY);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override a method, setRendermode in ballThrowSurfaceview class and call that overridden method in your touchevent class.